# Solve the recurrence $T(n)=T(n-1)+\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: recurrence-relation

Assume this recurrence:
$$T(n)=T(n-1)+\frac{1}{n}$$

As we can use Master Theorem and Akra-Bazzi method here, I tried to draw a recurrence tree and I reached the whole cost of this tree is $\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\dots+\frac{1}{n}$. What's a tight upper and lower bound for this recurrence (I'm talking about $\Theta$, not $\mathcal{O}$)? Is it even possible to find a $\Theta$ for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quantity $H_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}$ is known as the $n$-th [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).
It is well-known that $H_n = \Theta(\log n)$.

To see this notice that the function $\frac{1}{x}$ is monotonically decreasing, which means that the area under $\frac{1}{x}$ in the range $i \le x \le i+1$ is at most $\frac{1}{i}$ (i.e. the area of a rectangle of width $i+1 - i = 1$ and height $\frac{1}{i}$). In formulas: $\int_{i}^{i+1} \frac{1}{x} \text{d}x \le \int_{i}^{i+1} \frac{1}{i} \text{d}x = \frac{1}{i}$.

$$
H_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i} \ge 
\sum_{i=1}^n \int_{i}^{i+1} \frac{1}{x} \text{d}x =
\int_{1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{x} \text{d}x = \ln (n+1) = \Omega( \log n).
$$

Similarly, the area under $\frac{1}{x}$ in the range $i \le x \le i+1$ is at least $\frac{1}{i+1}$, i.e., $\int_{i}^{i+1} \frac{1}{x} \text{d}x \ge \int_{i}^{i+1} \frac{1}{i+1} \text{d}x = \frac{1}{i+1}$.

$$
H_n 
= 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{i+1}
\le 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \int_{i}^{i+1} \frac{1}{x} \text{d}x
= 1 + \int_{1}^{n} \frac{1}{x} \text{d}x=1+\ln n = O(\log n).
$$

Comment: Thanks. Can you please write or link a proof to it?

Comment: In the last line, is it $O(n)$ or $O(\log{n})$?

Comment: @IlkayBurak, clearly it is $O( \log n)$. Thanks for pointing out the typo :)